# Javascript setTimeout does not work

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I understand this question has been asked many times, however I cannot find the solution to my problem despite searching google and stackoverflow and applying various attempts.

Here's my JS:

```
    function Redirect(id)
    {
        window.open("go.php?id=" + id, "_blank");
    }

    function LinkPop(id)
    {           
        xmlObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlObj.open("GET", "pop.php?id=" + id, false);
        xmlObj.send();

        document.getElementById(id).style.fontSize = xmlObj.responseText + "px";
        document.getElementById(id).title = "Clicked " + (xmlObj.responseText - 18) + " times";

        window.setTimeout(function(){Redirect(id);}, 2000);
    }
```

Everything works apart from the 2 second delay and opening of a new page. As you can see I've tried a closure which has not helped. I expect I've missed something very basic...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks OK to me. What actually happens? Error? Does the `Redirect` function actually get hit? Also, in JS it's better to put opening braces on the same line, and not capitalise function names unless you plan to instantiate, rather than merely invoke, them.

Comment: Convert `xmlObj.responseText` to integer. Ensure that an element with the according `id` exists (`document.getElementById(id)` mustn't be null).

Comment: I placed the braces on the same lines, I used to programming a particular way with PHP and C. The Redirect() function does not appear to be called. I tested it with an alert() call.

Comment: @Jasd the IDs match up fine. Everything relating to the manipulated DOM works fine. I'm making my own tag cloud and once a second or so has been passed, allowing the font increase to be noticed, then I'd like the user to be directed to where ID in the DB dictates.

Comment: Why is my post marked down? Thus far this is a unique problem, seeing as no one has been able to solve it?

Comment: @Lee See the FAQ. In particular, your question shows lack of research and attempts by you to diagnose the problem even after hints. You're aware that it has been asked many times; show us where and why that's relevant. You've said you googled – using which keywords? Have you checked sites such as https://developer.mozilla.org/ for an answer? There's no popup after 2 seconds. Are there indications as to why (location bar in Chrom(ium|e), status bar elsewhere)? Are statements other than window.open() executed after 2 seconds? In case of a popup blocker, it is foolish to try to work around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to open a pop-up window. All modern browsers have pop-up blockers that will prevent you from doing so except in restricted circumstances, due to past abuses of this feature.

In particular, browsers typically allow pop-ups only in direct response to an interaction (eg click) with the web page. A timeout event is not an interaction, even if it was fired in response to an earlier interaction, so you won't be allowed to open the window for default settings.

You can open the pop-up straight away (you can try opening it as a pop-under and focusing it later to bring it to the front, although this isn't always reliable). Or, probably better, forget the pop-ups and just do a simple redirect on the current page.